# Calculating Size Dimensions in PHP

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to put together a simple calculation.

I have a size dimension of 100 x 100 x 100 which is a box.

I have individual items of 50 x 50 x 50.

If I keep adding items, I want to work out how many boxes is required to hold those items.

For example:

> If I have 1 item of (50x50x50) then I will need 1 box to hold that item.

> If I have 2 items of (50x50x50) then I will need 1 box to hold those 2 items.

> If I have 3 items of (50x50x50) then I will need 2 boxes to hold those 3 items.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ceil(3*(50/100))`. 3 would be the input 3 items of (50x50x50).

Comment: Thanks @DokuDoki could you add your answer in the box so I can vote for it? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

function GetItemsInBoxQuantity ($boxsize = array(100, 100,100), $verifiable_item = array(50,50,50)) { # here we pass default values of box size and verifable items
    $boxspace = array_product($boxsize);
    $verifiable_item_space = array_product($verifiable_item);
    $count_boxes_in_boxspace = floor($boxspace / $verifiable_item_space);
    return $count_boxes_in_boxspace;
}

# Now we putting new values of box size and size of items
$box = array(200,100,100);
$verifiable_item= array(40,40,40);

$result = GetItemsInBoxQuantity($box, $verifiable_item);
echo 'We can put into box '.$result.' items.';

?>
```

Output:

We can put into box 31 items.